# is it possible to pass variables into the oracle apex application success message box

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to output results from a function that is run within my oracle apex application, is it possible to pass variables into the oracle apex application success message box. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the item is on the same page as the success message box is on, then use this format:

`&ITEMNAME.`

This will display the value of the `ITEMNAME` item.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to an item value using the `&P1_ITEM.` syntax, or you can add a Process which sets APEX_APPLICATION.g_print_success_message, e.g.

```
APEX_APPLICATION.g_print_success_message := 'Hello ' || localvar;
```